# react onChange on text field update whole component when state is changed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, react-state

I had a functional component and using react hooks to manage the state.

As soon as I add onChange in textField(input in material UI) the whole components re-render and when I remove the onChange in textField it does not re-render

```js
            <TextField
                    id='outlined-basic'
                    label='Outlined'
                    variant='outlined'
                    fullWidth
                    onChange={e => {
                        setChannelUrl(e.target.value);
                    }}
                />
```

[image]

The above picture is of component is rerender even I am not passing any props.

As soon as I remove `setChannelUrl(e.target.value);`  everythng works like fine.

setChannelUrl is react useState Hooks

```
    const [channelUrl, setChannelUrl] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('runnedddd');
        return () => {};
    }, []);
    const classes = useStyle();
    return (
        <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.root}>
            <Grid item md={6}>
                <Typography variant='h6' color='primary' className={classes.button}>
                    Please Enter Your Channel Url
                </Typography>
                <TextField
                    id='outlined-basic'
                    label='Outlined'
                    variant='outlined'
                    fullWidth
                    onChange={e => {
                        setChannelUrl(e.target.value);
                    }}
                />

                <Button fullWidth color='primary' variant='contained'>
                    large
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item md={6}>
                <Paper elevation={2} className={`flex flexColumn ${classes.w100}`}>
                    <Avatar alt='Remy Sharp' src=''>
                        H
                    </Avatar>
                    <Typography variant='body' align='center'>
                        Hitesh Choudary
                    </Typography>

                    <Button
                        fullWidth
                        color='primary'
                        variant='contained'
                        className={classes.button}
                    >
                        Save It
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        fullWidth
                        color='secondary'
                        variant='contained'
                        className={classes.button}
                    >
                        No, its not mine
                    </Button>
                    <Stats />
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
};
```

stats component

```
import React from 'react';

const Stats = props => {
    console.log(props);

    return <div></div>;
};

export default Stats;
```

I am using functional component and arrow function

Comment: That's the correct behaviour. The component where the state lives re-renders when you change state that uses the hook

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash the question is completely clear, we don't need an example to understand this. it's basic react behaviour

Comment: @azium you are right...

Comment: @jsRook so what's the problem? Are you still confused about something?

Comment: @azium I am new to hooks but I had worked with class-based component and it does not happen there

Comment: It's not basic react behavior when your component renders without using `onChange`, as I understand it, the component renders without typing in the field. That's why he needs to re-phrase the question and I downvoted.

Comment: That's not true, in both the class version and the hook version the component will re-render when state changes

Comment: @DennisVash oh you might be right, I was assuming the logs were being generated by the user typing into the text field

Comment: @azium that means whole compoent will re-render ?

Comment: The component where you call `this.setState` or `setChannelUrl` it will re-render itself and all its children

Comment: @DennisVash my componet is re-rendering when the any user types  in the text field

Comment: So show us where are the logs coming from, who is the parent, what is the structure, what is the desired behavior?

Comment: I think the short answer here is "yes the entire component re-renders everytime you change state" and this is how it works and it's fine, there's nothing to worry about

Comment: @azium the log is generating as soon as the user starts typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stats` component renders duo to its parent render.

The parent renders when users typing in text field and `onChange` updates the stated through `setChannelUrl`.

You can memoize `Stats` with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) which will prevent the undesired renders:

> If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

```
const Stats = () => {
    // Won't log on parent render
    console.log('rendered');
    return <div></div>;
};

export default React.memo(Stats);
```

Comment: This is a fine answer, I will just add as a caution that it's not necessarily advisable to prevent renders using `memo`. It's good as a performance optimization in situations where hundreds or thousands of renders can be prevented. In most cases letting React render is fine and easier to reason about